# Syntax for finding multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, xml, xpath

I am using the following jQuery XPath to find any element with the attribute "pathname" (a variable that takes the page location from the URL).

```
var local_url = "*[url=" + pathname + "]";
```

However, I now want to find whether this variable exists in one of two element attributes: url or alturl. How would I phrase this in XPath syntax so I don't have to use an if/else statement? (Eg, find all attributes where url=pathname OR alturl = pathname.)

Thanks!

Comment: That is actually a CSS selector. Doesn't XPath selectors prefix the attribute with `@` ?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple XPath solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to find elements with either attribute matching, for example:

```
$("[url=" + pathname + "], [alturl=" + pathname + "]")
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would I phrase this in XPath
>   syntax so I don't have to use an
>   if/else statement? (Eg, find all
>   attributes where url=pathname OR
>   alturl = pathname.)

**This XPath expression**:

```
*[@url='someString' or @alturl='someString']
```

selects all elements that are children of the current node and have an attribute `url` with value `'someString'` or (non-exclusive) have an attribute `alturl` with value `'someString'` .

Answer (score 0):

> I now want to find whether this
>   variable exists in one of two element
>   attributes

This is exactly the behavior of node set comparison:

```
*[(@url|@alturl)='someString']
```